# Flux outward Sphere-Cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

$D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 25,y^2+z^2\le 9\}$

$F=\{y^2,x^2,z\}$

I need to calculate the flux outward the boundary of $D$.

I think I can use the divergent theorem, but How can I define the triple integral of the whole surface? Or Do I need to divide the surface into 3 parts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Divergence Theorem. That is, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\iint_E \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S} &= \iiint_E \text{div} (\mathbf{F}) \:dV \\
&= \iiint_E \langle \partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z \rangle \cdot \langle y^2,x^2,z \rangle \: dV \\
&= \iiint_E  \partial_x(y^2) + \partial_y(x^2) + \partial_z(z) \: dV \\
&=\iiint_E 1 \:dV \\
&=\iiint_E 1 \:dx \: dy \: dz\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{-\sqrt{25-r^2}}^{\sqrt{25-r^2}} \left|\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(x,r,\theta)}   \right| dx \: dr \: d\theta \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{-\sqrt{25-r^2}}^{\sqrt{25-r^2}} \big|r\big| \: dx \: dr \: d\theta \\  
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{-\sqrt{25-r^2}}^{\sqrt{25-r^2}} r \: dx \: dr \: d\theta \hspace{4mm} 
\mbox{ since }r \geq 0 \\  
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3}  r (2\sqrt{25-r^2}) \: dr  \\ 
&= - 2\pi \int_{25}^{16} \sqrt{u}\: du \hspace{4mm} 
\mbox{ where }u = 25-r^2, \hspace{4mm} 
\mbox{ so } \hspace{4mm} 
du = -2r \:dr
\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{3}\left( 5^3 - 4^3 \right) \\
&= \boxed{\frac{244}{3}\pi} \\
\end{align*}
$$
since given a parametrization in cylindrical coordinates
$$
\mathbf{r}(x,r,\theta) 
= \langle x(x,r,\theta), y(x,r,\theta), z(x,r,\theta)\rangle 
= \langle x,r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta\rangle, \hspace{4mm}
r \geq 0 
\hspace{4mm}
\mbox{ and } 
\hspace{4mm}
0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi,  
$$
its Jacobian is 
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(x,r,\theta)} 
&= 
\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}  \\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}   \\ 
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} \\ 
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= 
\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0& 0 \\ 
0 & \cos \theta & -r \sin \theta \\ 
0 &\sin \theta  & r \cos \theta \\ 
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= r. 
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: exactly! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to convert to [cylindrical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system), with $z$ being identified with the $x$-axis. (A diagram helps) The integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^3\int_{-\sqrt{25-r^2}}^{\sqrt{25-r^2}}r\cdot \text{div}(F)\ dz\ dr\ d\theta$$
Where $r$ is the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) of the transformation $(r,\theta,z)\mapsto (z,r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$. The integral isn't so hard, so I'll leave it to "u" to finish :)

Comment: shouldn't it be $dxdrd\theta$ ? becouse my cylinder is parallel to the x-axis

Comment: @NPLS you can use $dx \: dr \: d\theta$ or $dz \: dr \: d\theta$, where we identify the variable $z$ to be the coordinate along the $x$-axis.